# Eclipse does not open

Tags: 14.04, java, eclipse, openjdk

I've installed Eclipse 3.8 through Ubuntu Software Center and when I open it the loading window pops up and freezes. Eclipse  never opens... 
When I try to launch eclipse from Terminal it doesn't show anything, no errors, nothing, it just freezes...Though I get a log file in my home folder:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8435565/

Here some info about my system:

```
Ubuntu 14.04

java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

**Content of eclipse.ini file:**

```
-startup

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar

--launcher.library

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.dist

-showsplash

org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

256m

--launcher.defaultAction

openFile

-vmargs

-Xms40m

-Xmx384m

-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

Answer (score 0):

The versions in the Launchpad Archives are always out of date and often problematic. Go to [Eclipse's website](https://www.eclipse.org) and download the latest version (4.4 Luna currently).